# Como corrigir problema com caracteres especiais em Knitr::kable e kableExtra para um relatório PDF

Tags: r

Estou tentando personalizar uma tabela usando R Sweave. O problema é que a saída do R bagunça o símbolo \ , em alguns casos não saí a barra \ no arquivo .tex o que causa erro, mas já corrigi usando gsub(). O problema agora é que no lugar da barra \ está saindo \textbackslash{} e no lugar de { está saindo {.

Um exemplo curto contendo o erro:

Este o código do arquivo .Rnw

```
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\chapter{Something}

<<echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE>>=
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

#CONFIGURANDO UMA CELULA COM LOGICA

a<-c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5")
b<-c(70,45,80,55,20)
c<-data.frame(a,b)
colnames(c)<-c("Name", "Grade")
library(dplyr)
d<-c%>%
  mutate(
    Grade=cell_spec(Grade,"latex",color=ifelse(Grade>=60,"blue","red")))


d<-kable(d, "latex", booktabs=T, row.names = FALSE, align="c")
@

\Sexpr{gsub("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\", d)}

\end{document}
```

No arquivo .tex o resultado é o seguinte

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\input{teste-concordance}

\chapter{Something}



\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
Name & Grade\\
\midrule
Name1 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{blue\}\{70\}\\
Name2 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{45\}\\
Name3 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{blue\}\{80\}\\
Name4 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{55\}\\
Name5 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{20\}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Alguma maneira de resolver?

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

A questão acima foi resolvida, mas estou com um problema parecido novamente:

O arquivo .Rnw com este código

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\chapter{Something}

<<echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE>>=
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

#CONFIGURANDO UMA CELULA COM LOGICA

a<-c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5")
b<-c(70,45,80,55,20)
c<-data.frame(a,b)
colnames(c)<-c("Name", "Grade")
library(dplyr)
d<-c%>%
  mutate_if( is.numeric, function(x) { cell_spec(x, "latex", bold = T, color = spec_color(x, end = 0.9),font_size = spec_font_size(x))})%>%
  mutate(
    Grade=cell_spec(Grade,"latex",color=ifelse(Grade>=60,"blue","red")))



d<-kable(d, "latex", booktabs=T, row.names = FALSE, align="c", escape=F)
@

\Sexpr{gsub("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\", d)}

\end{document}
```

produz este arquivo .tex, que não está correto

```
\documentclass{book}  
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\input{teste-concordance}

\chapter{Something}



\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
Name & Grade\\
\midrule
Name1 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}bgroup\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}fontsize\textbackslash{}\{15\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{17\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}selectfont \textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textcolor[HTML]\textbackslash{}\{5DC962\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textbf\textbackslash{}\{70\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}egroup\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}\}\}\\
Name2 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}bgroup\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}fontsize\textbackslash{}\{11\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{13\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}selectfont \textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textcolor[HTML]\textbackslash{}\{2C718E\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textbf\textbackslash{}\{45\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}egroup\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}\}\}\\
Name3 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}bgroup\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}fontsize\textbackslash{}\{16\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{18\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}selectfont \textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textcolor[HTML]\textbackslash{}\{BBDF27\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textbf\textbackslash{}\{80\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}egroup\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}\}\}\\
Name4 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}bgroup\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}fontsize\textbackslash{}\{13\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{15\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}selectfont \textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textcolor[HTML]\textbackslash{}\{1F968B\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textbf\textbackslash{}\{55\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}egroup\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}\}\}\\
Name5 & \textbackslash{}textcolor\{red\}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}bgroup\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}fontsize\textbackslash{}\{8\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{10\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}selectfont \textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textcolor[HTML]\textbackslash{}\{440154\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}textbf\textbackslash{}\{20\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}\}\textbackslash{}textbackslash\{\}egroup\textbackslash{}\{\textbackslash{}\}\}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tenta colocar `escape = F` em `kable`

Comment: Ótimo! Resolvido. Como esta opção não tinha resolvido o problema inicial que era omitir a barra \ na saída, nem tentei mais usa-lo. Muito obrigado

Comment: por nada!! irei postar como resposta então!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolver tal problema, basta colocar:

`escape = F` em `kable`

```
d<-kable(d, "latex", booktabs=T, row.names = FALSE, align="c", escape = F)
```

Sempre que tu utiliza um caracter especial, ou a tua função gera um código bruto html/`LaTeX` (que nesse caso a função `cell_spec` gera um código `LaTeX`), você precisa falar para o kable não "**escapar** tais caracters/códigos".

Comment: editei a pergunta, o problema inicial foi resolvido, mas uma nova modificação na tabela está gerando o mesmo erro mesmo com escape=F

Comment: mas qual é o erro? Não seria melhor fazer uma outra pergunta?

Comment: está saindo `\textbackslash{}` no lugar da barra invertida  e   `\{ `    no lugar de `{` e `\}` no lugar de `}`